# $2-2n=3n+17$ - Not sure why my approach is incorrect

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

In this equation, I'm trying to understand why my solution doesn't work.

The answer is $n=-3$.

I intially thought to get the $n$ on its own I'll just add $2$ to each side for e.g

$-2n+2n = 0n$ and $3n + 2n = 5n$

So we've got $5n$.

But in the answer examples they subtracted $3n$ from both sides resulting in $-5n$.

Why is my approach the wrong way? And how should I know whether to add or subtract?

Or is my approach fine aswell I've just calculated it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: $5n$ is correct. The other side then is $2-17=-15$. So $n=-3$ as you said. Of course you could switch sides, so look at $-5n=15$. This is equivalent, as you know.

Comment: Whether you move them to the right, or move them to the left doesn't matter.  It should end the same way.  If we move to the right you should arrive at $2-17 = 3n - (-2n)$ or $-15 = 5n$ which you can then divide to get $-3 = n$.  Alternatively if you move it to the left you get $-2n-3n = 17-2$ which is $-5n = 15$ after which you can divide to get $n=-3$.  Of course $n=-3$ and $-3=n$ both mean the same thing in the end.

Comment: Thanks, what I did was I saw I had 2 on the lhs and 17 on the rhs and just thought I'll take 2 from each side.

2 - 2 = 0 and 17 - 2 = 15 so I just assumed I was left with positive 15.

I guess that's the wrong way to think about it? I kind of disregarded the actual equation.

Comment: The punchline should be that you can perform whatever simplifications and whatever rearrangements you like... whether they exactly match what order other people do them in or not... so long as you do them correctly and they help progress you towards a final simplified result that is easier to use than the result you started with.  There can sometimes be *many* ways to do something in math.

Comment: I'll give you another example, I was just doing:

17+4h+2=1-5h.

I thought if I take 1 from both sides I'll be left with:

17 + 2 = 19 - 1 = 18

18 + 4h = -5h

And then if I add 5 to both the h sides I'll be left with:

18 + 9h.

so I assumed h was 2 as 9x2 = 18.

I've just checked the answer and it was -2, so I'd made the same mistake.

Where did I go wrong there? :D

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "*I'll give you another example... I'll be left with $18+9h$*"  That is not an equation, that is an expression.  You are left with $18+9h=0$.  The equals sign is important and can't be left out.  Sure, you can divide both sides by $9$ and you'll have $2+h=0$.  Now, if you want to see what $h$ is equal to... you want to keep the $h$'s on one side... *and move everything else to the other side*.  So, from $2+h=0$ you move the $2$ to get $h=-2$.  Make sure you understand the difference between $18+9h=0$ and $18=9h$.  Those are two very different equations.